# Why does my Vaillant boiler shut itself off every day?

Tags: boiler, hot-water

I'm subtenant and I have Vaillant boiler (don't know which model). Every time I use shower after few minutes boiler shuts itself down and the burner lockout indicator is flashing. I'm then without hot water and central heating.

When it shuts down, I start it by pressing the red button. Some times it only provides water to run the central heating.

I've called a repairman and he couldn't solve the problem, he even asked 2 of his colleagues, they couldn't solve the problem either. Here is the picture of boiler and burner lockout indicator:

[image]

Comment: IIUC, sometimes when you restart it, it will start, but only provides heating water, not hot tap water? Have you tried adjusting temperatures to see if lower temps will make a difference (you may not want a shower that cool, but at least would be a clue)? Have you tried turning it off & leaving it off for 30-60 minutes - there may be an internal memory in the controller board that's corrupt and needs to be off for a while to reset itself.

Comment: When it stops working flame is extinguished and I don't have central heating nor hot tap water. Then I restart boiler with red button and everything works for a short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

I used most the obvious solution: replace whole electronic parts with new ones. I haven't had any problems since then.